# Assumptions of the MCT

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Monotone Convergence Theorem:

Let ($f_n$) be a sequence in $\Sigma^+$ (i.e. measurable and nonnegative), such that $f_{n+1}\geq f_n$ almost everywhere for each $n$.
Let $f=\limsup_n f_n$.
Then $\mu (f_n)\uparrow \mu (f)\leq \infty$.

Can it be deduced that $f$ is measurable?

Answer (score 3):

$f_n$ has to be measurable in order for

$$
\mu(f_n) = \int f_n d\mu
$$

to be defined at all (at least for the usual definition of the integral).

Measurability of $f$ follows, because if each $f_n$ is measurable, you can show that the same is true of

$$
g_n := \sup_{\ell \geq n} f_\ell
$$

for all $n$ (consider $g_n^{-1}((c,\infty])) = \bigcup_{\ell \geq n} f_\ell^{-1}((c,\infty))$), so that

$$
\limsup_n f_n = \lim_n \sup_{\ell \geq n} f_\ell
$$

is also measurable (because pointwise limits of measurable functions are measurable).

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but don't you mean `Measurability of $f$ follows, because ...'?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the comment, I will fix it.